# Scope issue in html page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I believe this is a *scope* issue but I haven't been able to resolve it, you can see some of the things I have tried commented out, maybe you can solve it. I have a variable, for purposes of StackOverflow I have named it `undefinedVar` and I try to call a method owned? by that variable but when I do I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: undefinedVar is not defined`. Now, there is obviously a whole lot more in this .html file but none of that matters for this question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    varX.ready(functionName);
    function functionName() {
        varX.ready(unDefinedVar.itsFunction());
    };
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="#stackOverflow">

        <div id="demo"></div>

    </div><!-- End of the #stackOverflowDiv --> 

</body>
    <script>
    //$(document).ready( function () {
    //$( function () {
       unDefinedVar = kendo.observable({
          randomVariable: [],
          itsFunction: function () {
              #blahblahblah
          }
       });
    //});    //end $function
    //});    //End Document.ready

    </script>
</html>
```

..or what would be the proper way to make this work?

Comment: Your example is incomplete. What is `varX`?

Comment: it is in another file that gets imported

Comment: Why is the second script tag outside the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the function after you've defined `undefinedVar`, so it looks like this:

```js
undefinedVar = kendo.observable({
   randomVariable: [],
   itsFunction: function () {
       #blahblahblah
   }
});

function functionName() {
    varX.ready(undefinedVar.itsFunction());
};    
varX.ready(functionName);
```

Also, you've defined `undefinedVar`, but are looking to reference `unDefinedVar`.  Make sure the case matches!